# Offline Here maps with MapLoader

Tags: android, here-api

I'm trying to install the maps here in the application, but when running mapLoader.getMapPackages (); I get nullpointerexception error.

At what point should I do the installation of maps to be available offline?

Comment: Hi celebe,I also stuck for this problem. please respond if you resolved this problem

Answer (score 0):

Has the system been initialized via:
com.here.android.mpa.common.MapEngine#init( OnEngineInitListener listener )
or 
com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment#init( OnEngineInitListener listener ) ?

Without initialization, the map loader will not be able to start correctly.